# Keyboard shortcuts in Google Slides Add-on

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, google-slides, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm creating an add-on for Google Slides. My add-on consists of a single button in HTML. Instead of having the user click on the button (which performs an action to the slide), is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut that automatically clicks the button or "calls" the script function?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

The add-on is in a separate iframe and doesn't have visibility to any keyboard events in the main window. It could capture events in the add-on window, but it only works if the focus is already on the add-on. The overhead of setting the focus properly makes the keyboard shortcut not so useful.